# MusicPlayer Pause and Start from it the start

Tags: android, android-activity, android-music-player

I am developing music application .

I want to pause the player and when I go for resume it will start it from the that point.

**Music.java**

```
public class Music {

    private static MediaPlayer mp = null;

    public static void play(Context context,int resource){
        stop(context);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, resource);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }

    static void stop(Context context) {
        if(mp != null){
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }
}
```

SMusicActivity

```
public class SMusicActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btnplay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        btnplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onResume();
            }
        });

        Button btnstop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause);
        btnstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPause();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Music.play(this,R.raw.govind_bolo);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Music.stop(this);
    }
}
```

I want to use stop button as Pause and play .
I did coding for it but as you know I didn't get perfect one ..So
How can I make operation like Play and Pause into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of your static Music Facade. Use a real MediaPlayer in your activity and

- instanciate it only once (onCreate)
- put it to play and pause when buttons are clicked
- check with mediaPlayer.isPlaying() that you can actually play or pause the player. There is a state diagram to respect when using this object, see the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for further details of states and allowed transitions from specific states.

Answer (score 0):

Create a local variable like "private int currentPosition", then use the following:

```
    btnplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.seekTo(currentPosition);
            onResume();
        }
    });

    Button btnstop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause);
    btnstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            onPause();
        }
    });
```